# Display User Control content as Image (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, infragistics

I'm trying to serialize `XamRadialGauge` user control to XAML (by `Infragistics`).

This UC is not serializble, so I've created a new UserControl that contains a private `XamRadialGauge` , and I want to bind my new user control `Content` to the `XamRadialGauge` Content AS IMAGE.

I've tryied to take a snapshot from the `XamRadialGauge` content, but I was unable to show it as Image in my UC.

Can someone throw me a bone here ?

Comment: Because its a generic application, therefore we can't add this UC hard coded,I'm asking how can I create UC that shows only image in it content regardless of serializing the object.